# Tomar dato de sql y marcarlo como lo activo o lo actual

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Quiero hacer esto en php quizás no sepa explicarme bien así que si falta modificarle no se preocupen yo puedo hacerlo rápido ya que me siento en mi pc

Tengo una tabla cuya solo tiene 2 variables (ACTIVO) y (NO ACTIVO)

```
$sql = mssql("select estado from table where item = 'pesado'"); 
$temp = mssql_fetch_array ($sql);
```

Necesito que el **type ='radio'** se marque si esta activo *¿Como puedo hacerlo a partir de un select?*

```
<td WIDTH = 100> 
    <input size='1' type ='radio' value='ACTIVO' name='estado'>SI 
    <input size='7' type ='radio' value='NO ACTIVO' name='estado'>NO
</td>
```

OK amigos como veran enseguida vi 4 comentarios me active a probar e intentado esto pero me da error

sera mas concreto:

```
<?php
include "../../includes/db_connect_mysql.php"; 
$sql = mysqli_query($conexion,"
SELECT 
id, 
nombre, 
nombre_esp, 
nombre_eng, 
nombre_bra, 
orden, 
estado, 
id_padre, 
seccion
FROM sr_productos_categorias
WHERE orden > 0 and seccion = 'tienda' ORDER BY orden ASC
");
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){

echo
"Item a Editar;
<table border=1 aling=left WIDTH= 580>
<tr>

 <td WIDTH= 280><font color=#FF000> Categoria Nombre: </font></td>
 <td WIDTH= 50><font color=#FF000> Orden: </font></td>
 <td WIDTH= 100><font color=#FF000> Estado: </font></td>
 <td WIDTH= 110><font color=#FF000> Sub-Categoria: </font></td>

</tr>
</table>
"; while ($temp[6] = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
print
"<table border=1 aling=left WIDTH= 580>
<tr>

 <td WIDTH = 280><input type ='radio' name='codigo' value='".$temp["codigo"]."'>".$temp["nombre_esp"]."</td>
 <td WIDTH = 50><input size='1' type='text' placeholder = 'orden' name='orden' value='".$temp["orden"]."' /></td>
    <td WIDTH = 100> 
        <input size='1' type ='radio' 
";
<?php ($temp[6] === true ? echo 'checked'  : null) ?> 
print
"
value='ACTIVO' name='estado'>SI 
        <input 
";
<?php ($temp === false ? echo 'checked'  : null) ?>
print
"
 size='7'  type ='radio' value='NO ACTIVO' name='estado'>NO
    </td>
 <td WIDTH = 110><name='orden' /><a href='#'>Editar</a></td>

</tr>
</table>
";}
 echo
"
"
 ;} else{
 echo"No hay datos";}
?>
```

que tengo que corregir?

Answer (score 3):

A la hora de pintar esos checkbox debes comprobar el resultado de la consulta y pintar *checked* en caso de que este activo.

```
<td WIDTH = 100> 
  <input size='1' type ='radio' id='ACTIVO' <?php $estado == 'activo' ? echo 'checked' : null; ?> name='estado'>SI 
  <input size='7' type ='radio' id='NO ACTIVO' <?php $estado == 'no activo' ? echo 'checked' : null; ?> name='estado'>NO
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Deberas evaluar el resultado de la sentencia sql, el cual te devolvera el estado, entiendo que sera un valor booleano. Ese valor lo tienes que guardar en una variable por ejemplo:
$status
Para marcarlo como seleccionado hay que hacer un condicional, en este caso los ternarios van muy bien.

```
    <td WIDTH = 100> 
        <input size='1' type ='radio' <?php ($status === true ? echo "checked"  : null) ?> value='ACTIVO' name='estado'>SI 
        <input <?php ($status === false ? echo "checked"  : null) ?> size='7'  type ='radio' value='NO ACTIVO' name='estado'>NO
    </td>
```

Espero que la idea te pueda servir para solucionar tu problema.

Comment: la variable es `$sql` no `$status` (aunque seria mas logico lo tuyo claro) además, la consulta no devuelve string?  tu haces `=== true`

Comment: Yo entiendo que el campo estado tiene dos valores: "activo" y "no activo"... ¿No?

Comment: el resultado de la consulta no lo puedo ver, puesto que no tengo el output de la misma, pero simplemente si te devuelve un string tienes que evaluar el string, si es activo lo que devuelve cambia === true por === "activo"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar JS:

```
var resultado = "<?php echo $sql; ?>";
```

He cambiado tu atributo `value` por `ID`
Suponiendo que el resultado es como el ID("ACTIVO" , "NO ACTIVO") puedes hacer:

```
<td WIDTH = 100> 
    <input size='1' type ='radio' id='ACTIVO' name='estado'>SI 
    <input size='7' type ='radio' id='NO ACTIVO' name='estado'>NO
</td>


document.getElementById(resultado).checked = true;
```